# nature.cls class breaks figure numbering

Tags: cross-referencing

The figure environment is redefined in `nature.cls` [as follows](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nature/nature.cls):

```
\renewenvironment{figure}{\let\caption\NAT@figcaption}{}

\newcommand{\NAT@figcaption}[2][]{\AtEndDocument{%
\refstepcounter{figure}
\ifthenelse{\value{figure}=1}{
    \newpage\noindent%
%        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
}{
    \par\vfill
}
\sffamily\noindent\textbf{Figure \arabic{figure}}\hspace{1em}#2}
}
```

When compiling a document with this class, figure numbers are lost (i.e., the `\label`/`\ref` mechanism appears to be broken).  I believe this is because of the redefinition of `\caption` in `nature.cls` (namely `\let\caption\NAT@figcaption`).  What changes are needed to restore numbering?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{nature}
\begin{document}

Fig.~\ref{fig1} shows\ldots

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Test}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Changing the class from `nature` to `article` restores figure numbering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `nature` class, the printout of the figures is delayed until `\end{document}`. Relevant here is that also the `\refstepcounter{figure}` is only called at the end of the document, so that the `\label` macro in your figure doesn't have a reference which it can pick up. You need to also delay the execution of the `\label` macro until the end of the document.

A simple way to do this is to include the `\label` macro inside the `\caption`. This modified MWE works as expected:

```
\documentclass{nature}
\begin{document}

Fig.~\ref{fig1} shows\ldots

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Test\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> Fig. 1 shows...

Comment: Thanks.  This behavior also prevents resetting of the figure counter in the middle (to distinguish main vs. supplemental figures).  Previously, one could make all the main figures, then simply reset the figure counter (`\setcounter{figure}{0}`), and proceed to make the supplementary figures.  Now that `\label` is executed at the end of the document, this act of resetting the counter has no effect.  I tried placing the counter reset within the caption of the first supplementary figure to delay its execution to `\end{document}`, to no avail.